# Woocommerce rest API - get products by list of sku's

Tags: python, woocommerce-rest-api

I tried to get product_details of a selected list of sku's out my woocommerce webshop by setting a list of sku's in the params of the call. When I use:

```
lst_of_skus = ['sku_1','sku_2']
response =wcapi.get("products", params={'sku':lst_of_skus}).json()
response
```

I only get a list with a dict of the last sku in the list. How can I get a list of dicts of all products in lst_of_skus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
skus =",".join(skus)
productlist=wcapi.get("products/?sku="+skus).json()
print(productlist)
```